# C++: Why "using" does not work in some cases?

Tags: c++11

This is OK:

```
template<typename T>
    using MyVector = std::vector<T>;

MyVector<int> xyz;
```

But not this:

```
template <typename F>
using MyCalc = float calc1(F f) { return -1.0f * f(3.3f) + 666.0f; }
```

though

```
template <typename F>
float calc1(F f) { return -1.0f * f(3.3f) + 666.0f; }
```

is OK. Is there a way to define an alias for calc1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using name = thing` declares a type alias. `calc1` is a template function, not a type. It's no different from declaring a variable and trying to use `using` to declare an alias to it.

There is no way to declare a function alias. There are many problems with doing so, due to C++'s various rules. Do you want the alias to be for an entire overload set or just one specific function? Should the alias include ADL or not? And so forth.